# Django DetailView getting values of ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, orm, detailview

I want to get post tags with ManyToMany relationship,  to display related posts with the same tags. The problem is that I don't know how to access the tags of the current post.

*model*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # author =
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='post_tags')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_to_read = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

*view*

```
class GetPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        post_tags = Post.tags.all()
        
       incorrect #context['related'] = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=post_tags)[:3]
```

am i need to override get_object?? or i can get it in context_data?

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the post tags with `self.object.tags.all()` so it will be something like :

```
context['related'] = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=self.object.tags.all()).distinct()[:3]
```

Add distinct because you can have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To display the `post` and `related` data in an HTML template in Django, you can use the following steps:

1. Create a new HTML file in the `templates` directory of your Django app. For example, you could create a file called `note_detail.html` in a subdirectory called `notes`.
2. In the `note_detail.html` file, you can use Django's template language to display the `post` and `related` data. For example:

   ```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}

   {% block content %}
   <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
   <p>{{ post.content }}</p>

   <h2>Related Posts</h2>
   <ul>
   {% for related_post in related %}
       <li><a href="{% url 'note_detail' related_post.pk %}">{{ related_post.title }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

   In this example, the `{{ post.title }}` and `{{ post.content }}` variables are used to display the title and content of the current post, and the `{% for related_post in related %}` loop is used to display a list of related posts. The `{% url 'note_detail' related_post.pk %}` template tag generates a URL to the detail view for each related post.
3. In your `NoteDetailView` class, set the `template_name` attribute to the name of the `note_detail.html` file you just created:

   ```
   class NoteDetailView(DetailView):
       model = Post
       template_name = 'notes/note_detail.html'
       context_object_name = 'post'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
           post_tags = self.object.tags.all()
           context['related'] = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=post_tags).distinct()[:3]
           return context
   ```
4. In your `urls.py` file, define a URL pattern that maps to the `NoteDetailView` class:

   ```
   from django.urls import path
   from .views import NoteDetailView

   urlpatterns = [
       path('notes/<int:pk>/', NoteDetailView.as_view(), name='note_detail'),
   ]
   ```

   In this example, the `NoteDetailView` class is mapped to the URL pattern `/notes/<int:pk>/`, where `<int:pk>` is the primary key of the post.
5. Finally, you can access the detail view for a post by visiting the URL `/notes/<post_pk>/`, where `<post_pk>` is the primary key of the post you want to view.